# Tor browser never crashed, now is

Tags: windows

It worked for years. I wish I'd used it more, given that it mostly sat around unappreciated. I re-downloaded and re-installed it weeks ago and again just an hour ago and got the same results. The Tor browser has stopped working. It doesn't even start, I get no popup about it connecting to the Tor network, just a bit of a busy cursor from Windows for a second, then nothing. The Windows Event Manager has this to say about it:

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: firefox.exe
P2: 52.3.0.6242
P3: 00000000
P4: KERNELBASE.dll
P5: 10.0.14393.1532
P6: 5965adf8
P7: c06d007f
P8: 000da9f2
P9: 
P10:

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_firefox.exe_ad623f51899d7f26a073e7e38314b34efae1fdde_a0b18c10_32f54da7

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: b879b153-6d4e-45a1-a831-f3eadab0f78f
Report Status: 2
Hashed bucket:

I develop device drivers in assembler, so I would appreciate not getting replies from people who have no idea what they're talking about. My Tor browser is installed in the default Windows 10 location it always installs itself in. I have re-installed the Tor browser in the usual default location of my Windows 10 desktop. The new installation is what the crash report above is about, but it was the same crash report before I re-installed the Tor browser.. which is why I re-installed it.

Comment: Anti-virus, Trusteer, similar "security" software is almost always the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly or not, I found another post here about Trusteer Rapport Endpoint protection. I had it installed and long before I ever installed the Tor browser. It makes no sense because it was installed before I downloaded Tor, and Tor worked fine but stopped working and I didn't update Tor or Rapport.

But I just uninstalled Rapport and now Tor is working fine.